# Не получается установить firebase на react js

Tags: reactjs

Почему то команда npm install --save firebase выдает ошибку:

````
npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@firebase%2fapp-types (over 30000ms)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-25T11_15_37_440Z-debug.log```
Помогите, пожалуйста.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже проблема с соедененим или оно слишком медленное. попробуй увеличить таймаут с 30сек до 60сек добавив в .npmrc файл:

```
timeout=60000
```

Если файла нет, можешь добавить файл туда же где находится `package.json`

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но можно по точнее как добавить timeout=60000 в package.json?

Comment: в `.npmrc`  файл